# how to fix the display format of the return result in python

Tags: python, if-statement, printing, readfile

i have a function that read file and display the matching word using regular expression .

the system display the result like this :

```
if
Exist on Line 1
if
Exist on Line 2
```

what i want is to make the result look like this :

```
if exist 2 times
on line 1
on line 2
```

## code:

```
def searchWord(self,selectedFile):
        fileToSearchInside = self.readFile(selectedFile)
        searchedSTR = self.lineEditSearch.text()

        textList = fileToSearchInside.split('\n')

        counter = 1
        for myLine in textList:
            theMatch = re.findall(searchedSTR,myLine,re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)

            if(len(theMatch) > 0 ):
                print(theMatch[0])
                print("Exist on Line {0}".format(counter))
                counter+=1
```

Comment: @Skandix no its based on the user input . what i want is the format of the displayed result to be improved

Comment: in the loop, store the individual lines and increment a counter. At the end of the loop, print all your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may keep a dict which maps keywords to all of their occurrences.

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)    # utility that gives an empty list for each key by default

for counter, myLine in enumerate(textList):
    matches = re.findall(searchedSTR, myLine, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(matches) > 0:
        d[matches[0]].append(counter + 1)  # add one record for the match (add one because line numbers start with 1)

for match, positions in d.items():   # print out
    print('{} exists {} times'.format(match, len(positions)))
    for p in positions:
        print("on line {}".format(p))
```

output would be like

```
if exists 2 times
on line 1
on line 2
```

As I couldn't tell from the description, if your application does not search multiple keywords, just forget the `dict` and use only one `list`.